# Colleagues feeling insecure when I do my work

Tags: communication, work-environment, colleagues, politics

I am a person who wants to learn and grow by doing challenging tasks that are assigned to me. Whenever I do some challenging work which helps the organization, a few of my colleagues feel insecure and start harassing me saying, "why have you worked without informing us", even though I informed them in several meetings. Is there anything wrong that I am thinking and why I am unable to work with them.

How can I resolve these issues so that I can do my work?

Comment: There's really not much info here. What work do you do? Who is your colleague - is he your peer? Do you do the same work? Is there a chance he might do the same work if you don't inform him?

Comment: I am learning on my own and unable to fight back and work.

Comment: He is my peer, yes I do the same work but differently. He wants to do it and he don't want me to do it.

Comment: What does your boss have to say about this?

Comment: I informed few times  but I know they are not going to change.

Comment: I don't want to argue with them as I feel it's not going to help rather they will do more such kind.

Comment: What issue needs to be resolved? Why is their insecurity your concern? If it were me, I'd ignore it.

Comment: " I informed them in several meetings" did you have any emails supporting that?

Comment: @SreekanthReddyIla 1) Are you doing some required task in a new way? (2) When you say you are doing challenging work, then is it something that was directly assigned by the boss? (3) Did the boss assign you in details about how to do the work or only on a higher level? (4) Is your situation something like this- boss asked you to do X without going into details of X. Then on your own you found some tools/faster/newer/better way of completing X? (5) Or did you do a POC for something new and pitch it to your boss after which your colleagues are angry with you for not telling.

Comment: @SreekanthReddyIla Answer my queries and I'll make your question a lot clearer to everyone. :)

Answer (score 4):

If this colleague isn't your boss, then ignore him and continue to do the work that was assigned to you.  If your colleague continues to harass you, then document the harassment as much as possible and report it to your company's HR.

Comment: But I don't want to create problem to them. Is there a solution without hurting them

Answer (score 4):

Your coworker literally wants to make you look bad in order to make himself look good and get the good assignments.  He's harassing you in order to make that happen.  This is not something you should put up with.  It will damage you, and damage your career.

Speak with your boss on the matter, *ask him what to do*, and then do what he tells you to.  If your coworkers continue to harass you about it, refer them to him.  You're just following orders.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios there are two things you can do.

First, if you have a direct technical senior/team lead then it is better to discuss with him/her on how you going few extra miles for your solution will help in betterment of the product. If your solution is more efficient than expected then your lead will always back you. That way you can continue to work the way you like.

Second, it is also equally important to be in healthy relationship with your colleagues, be genuine and friendly and offer your help if any of then are stuck. I feel like they are not familiar with your nature and mixing up with them would give them better idea of your work ethics.

I'd also point out that do not put your nose into their tasks unless asked. It will most likely worsen your relations.